# Stop PostgreSQL streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I want to make my PostgreSQL master / slave streaming replication setup into a single master slave setup without replication and without HA.

How is it possible to tell master that it no longer has slave and it should not replicate its data to the slave ?

Of course it should also not keep *WALs* to be sent to the slave as is done when the slave is temporarily down.

Comment: There is nothing you need to do. Just shut down the slave. Streaming replication is a "pull" replication - the slave actively retrieves the WAL records from the master.

Comment: If I shut down the slave doesn't the master accumulate WALs?  Isn't wal_keep_segments indicates how many WALs will be kept in Master in case data was not sent to slave?

Comment: from the docs: `Specifies the minimum number of past log file segments kept in the pg_xlog directory`. I believe it is a lower bound, not an upper bound.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the version of Postgres you're using, it's possible your replication is done using "replication slots".  If you don't have a client streaming from a replication slot anymore, you can drop the slot.  Here are some useful queries:

Get disk usage per replication slot (for Postgres 9.6):

```
SELECT
    redo_location,
    slot_name,restart_lsn,
    round((redo_location-restart_lsn) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS GB_behind
FROM
    pg_control_checkpoint(),
    pg_replication_slots;
```

Get disk usage per replication slot (for Postgres 10+):

```
SELECT redo_lsn,
    slot_name,
    restart_lsn,
    round((redo_lsn-restart_lsn) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS GB_behind
FROM pg_control_checkpoint(),
    pg_replication_slots;
```

Drop replication slot:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('slot_name');
```

References:

- https://severalnines.com/database-blog/using-postgresql-replication-slots :

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:

- on both master / slave, edit `pg_hba.conf`, remove:

  > host replication replicator x.x.x.x/32 md5
- in master, reload config, via:

  > select pg_reload_conf()
- in slave's data dir, remove file: `standby.signal`
- restart slave,

Then slave will keep the data, but don't replica from master any more, and slave is writable.

Comment: Which version of postgres is this for?

Comment: @KhoPhi `pg 13.4`

Comment: Thanks. I just asked for context. In 2072 when Postgres v 134.3 may not support this feature, in case somebody stumbles on this by then.

Comment: @KhoPhi 2072? You're funny man.

Answer (score 1):

it is **very important** to also stop walsender to recover server memory with the following command:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_replication;
```

this will free up your server storage memory.

Comment: The pid is determined by `select pid from pg_stat_replication;`?

Comment: After stopping the slave, pg_stat_replication is empty (pg version 15).

Comment: yes `select pid from pg_stat_replication;` will return the "PID", and it is necessary to stop walsender before stopping the slave, at least in postgreSQL version 13, sorry for the delay in getting back an answer, :)